# Convert list to data.table efficiently

Tags: r, data.table

I have a list that looks like this

```
    ans<-    list(structure(list(datetime_beginning_ept="2018-03-21T00:00:00",
pnode_id=1,total_lmp_rt=65.141702,congestion_price_rt=-0.94675,
marginal_loss_price_rt=0.048453),.Names=c("datetime_beginning_ept",
"pnode_id","total_lmp_rt","congestion_price_rt","marginal_loss_price_rt"
)),structure(list(datetime_beginning_ept="2018-03-21T00:00:00",
pnode_id=3,total_lmp_rt=57.007182,congestion_price_rt=-9.771097,
marginal_loss_price_rt=0.738279),.Names=c("datetime_beginning_ept",
"pnode_id","total_lmp_rt","congestion_price_rt","marginal_loss_price_rt"
)),structure(list(datetime_beginning_ept="2018-03-21T00:00:00",
pnode_id=48592,total_lmp_rt=48.61,congestion_price_rt=-17.31,
marginal_loss_price_rt=-0.12),.Names=c("datetime_beginning_ept",
"pnode_id","total_lmp_rt","congestion_price_rt","marginal_loss_price_rt"
)),structure(list(datetime_beginning_ept="2018-03-21T00:00:00",
pnode_id=48593,total_lmp_rt=48.61,congestion_price_rt=-17.31,
marginal_loss_price_rt=-0.12),.Names=c("datetime_beginning_ept",
"pnode_id","total_lmp_rt","congestion_price_rt","marginal_loss_price_rt"
)),structure(list(datetime_beginning_ept="2018-03-21T00:00:00",
pnode_id=48594,total_lmp_rt=47.35,congestion_price_rt=-18.7,
marginal_loss_price_rt=0.01),.Names=c("datetime_beginning_ept",
"pnode_id","total_lmp_rt","congestion_price_rt","marginal_loss_price_rt"
)),structure(list(datetime_beginning_ept="2018-03-21T00:00:00",
pnode_id=48595,total_lmp_rt=47.35,congestion_price_rt=-18.7,
marginal_loss_price_rt=0.01),.Names=c("datetime_beginning_ept",
"pnode_id","total_lmp_rt","congestion_price_rt","marginal_loss_price_rt"
)),structure(list(datetime_beginning_ept="2018-03-21T00:00:00",
pnode_id=48596,total_lmp_rt=47.35,congestion_price_rt=-18.7,
marginal_loss_price_rt=0.01),.Names=c("datetime_beginning_ept",
"pnode_id","total_lmp_rt","congestion_price_rt","marginal_loss_price_rt"
)),structure(list(datetime_beginning_ept="2018-03-21T00:00:00",
pnode_id=48603,total_lmp_rt=47.86,congestion_price_rt=-18.21,
marginal_loss_price_rt=0.03),.Names=c("datetime_beginning_ept",
"pnode_id","total_lmp_rt","congestion_price_rt","marginal_loss_price_rt"
)),structure(list(datetime_beginning_ept="2018-03-21T00:00:00",
pnode_id=48604,total_lmp_rt=47.86,congestion_price_rt=-18.21,
marginal_loss_price_rt=0.03),.Names=c("datetime_beginning_ept",
"pnode_id","total_lmp_rt","congestion_price_rt","marginal_loss_price_rt"
)),structure(list(datetime_beginning_ept="2018-03-21T00:00:00",
pnode_id=48605,total_lmp_rt=50.3,congestion_price_rt=-15.4,
marginal_loss_price_rt=-0.34),.Names=c("datetime_beginning_ept",
"pnode_id","total_lmp_rt","congestion_price_rt","marginal_loss_price_rt"
)))
```

I want to make it a data.table that looks like this...

```
pricedate              node_id         dalmp      damcc     damcl
1: 2018-03-21T00:00:00       1  100 65.14170  -0.946750  0.048453
2: 2018-03-21T00:00:00       3  100 57.00718  -9.771097  0.738279
3: 2018-03-21T00:00:00   48592  100 48.61000 -17.310000 -0.120000
4: 2018-03-21T00:00:00   48593  100 48.61000 -17.310000 -0.120000
5: 2018-03-21T00:00:00   48594  100 47.35000 -18.700000  0.010000
6: 2018-03-21T00:00:00   48595  100 47.35000 -18.700000  0.010000
7: 2018-03-21T00:00:00   48596  100 47.35000 -18.700000  0.010000
8: 2018-03-21T00:00:00   48603  100 47.86000 -18.210000  0.030000
9: 2018-03-21T00:00:00   48604  100 47.86000 -18.210000  0.030000
10: 2018-03-21T00:00:00   48605  100 50.30000 -15.400000 -0.340000
```

Right now I'm doing this

```
rbindlist(lapply(1:length(ans), function(x) {
  return(data.table(pricedate=ans[[x]]$datetime_beginning_ept, node_id=ans[[x]]$pnode_id, dalmp=ans[[x]]$total_lmp_rt,  damcc=ans[[x]]$congestion_price_rt, damcl=ans[[x]]$marginal_loss_price_rt))
}))
```

It works fine except in real life my `ans` is 50,000 rows long and I have to iterate over several cases of them and and each time it takes several minutes.  Is there a better way to make this transformation (besides parallelizing the task)?

Comment: What's wrong with `rbindlist(ans)`? It works for your example. Do you have some data frames with other columns in your data not shown here?

Comment: well this is embarrassing...i didn't know I could just do that.

Comment: No problem. Glad it's sorted out ;) `rbindlist` is quite fast, you shouldn't have performance issues

Comment: yeah, well I was using it, I just didn't know it would automatically convert the list to a data.table

Comment: @csgroen how to convert a list into datatable of differing length ?

Comment: @PesKchan, I think you'll need to subset your list items first to a common length, then you can `rbindlist` as well